# Invalid value error on Range Input WP Customizer

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Range input value not working in wp customizer.
This is my class for the wordpress customizer controll and bellow that is the js code.

```
<?php
    // Range Control Wwith Selected Value Indicator
    class WP_Customize_Range_Control extends WP_Customize_Control
    {
        public $type = 'custom_range';
        public function enqueue()
        {
            wp_enqueue_script(
                'cs-range-control',
                BLOCKS_URL . '/lib/js/controls.js',
                array('jquery-ui-slider'),
                false,
                true
            );
        }
        public function render_content()
        {
            ?>
            <label>
                <?php if ( ! empty( $this->label )) : ?>
                    <span class="customize-control-title"><?php echo esc_html($this->label); ?></span>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="cs-range-value"><?php echo esc_attr($this->value()); ?></div>
                <input data-input-type="range" type="range" <?php $this->input_attrs(); ?> value="<?php echo esc_attr($this->value()); ?>" <?php $this->link(); ?> />
                <?php if ( ! empty( $this->description )) : ?>
                    <span class="description customize-control-description"><?php echo $this->description; ?></span>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </label>
            <?php
        }
    }
```

// This is the JS

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('input[data-input-type="range"]').on('change', function () {
            var val = $(this).val();
            $(this).prev('.cs-range-value').html(val);
            $(this).val(val);
        });
    })
})(jQuery);
```

When i change the value of the slider in WP Customizer i get an error with Invalid value. Why is happening and how do i fix it ?

Comment: Instead of `$('input[data-input-type="range"]').on('change', function ()` try with `$(document).on('change', 'input[data-input-type="range"]', function ()`

Comment: Awesome...thank you bro :)

Comment: Still does not change value from value attribute. Edit: Finaly made it to work. Thanks again for help

Comment: What was the solution? Can you answer your question?

Comment: Check my answer bellow on how to modify options. Also change the enqued script to jquery only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
'sanitize_callback' => 'intval',
```

Answer (score 1):

Fix:
Changed the enqued script to jquery only then made
settings without sanitize callback (previously used sanitize intvl like wp says)
Something like this.

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'wca_header_opacity', array(
    'default' => '',
    'transport' => 'postMessage',
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_control(
    new WP_Customize_Range_Control(
        $wp_customize,
        'header_opacity',
        array(
            'label'       => __('Header Opacity When Fixed'),
            'section'     => 'wca_header_section_design',
            'settings'    => 'wca_header_opacity',
            'context'    => 'wca_header_opacity',
            'description' => __('Set transparency for header when is fixed for an awesome effect !'),
            'input_attrs' => array(
                'min' => 0,
                'max' => 1,
                'step' => 'any',
            ),
            'priority'   => 10
        )
    )
    );
```

Comment: I need something else...because without sanitization is unsafe and theme won't pass theme check plugin test!